# get the length of a string and assign it to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, string-length

Total c++ newbie here.

I have a problem, where I can not assign the number of character in a string to an array size, like so..

```
string outStr;
ifstream input("read.txt");
getline(input, outStr);

int const n = outStr.length();
int arr[n];
```

error msg --> expression must have a constant value. although i have declared the "const"

Thanks in advance✌.

Comment: You can't do that in C++.

Comment: `int arr[n]` is not allowed (without non-standard language extensions) if `n` is not known at compile time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not support Variable Length Arrays. Use a [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: thank bro, will read it.

Comment: it actually helped. thanks mate.